# Python calling mock with "=" not called result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mocking, pytest, assertion

I am trying to mock the following call:

```
df_x = method() # returns a pandas dataframe
df_x.loc[df_x['atr'] < 0, 'atr'] = 0
```

I have mocked the method so it returns a MagicMock and set a default value to the __ getitem__ attribute of the MagicMock as like this:

```
mock_df_x = mock_method.return_value
mock_df_x.__getitem__.return_value = 0
```

The problem is when I try asserting the call:

```
mock_df_x.loc.__getitem__.assert_called_with(False, 'atr')
```

I get a function not called error. If I call the function like this without the "= 0" part the assertion works.

```
df_x.loc[df_x['atr'] < 0, 'atr']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this different behavior depending on whether on you have `= 0` at the end of the call you are testing is that in [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), those correspond to two different magic methods: [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__).

This makes sense, because for example doing `some_dictionary['nonexistent_key]'` raises `KeyError`, whereas `some_dictionary['nonexistent_key]' = 1` doesn't, and sets the value as expected.

Now, in order to fix your test, you only need to change your assertion from:

```
mock_df_x.loc.__getitem__.assert_called_with((False, 'atr'))
```

which only works if you are accessing the key, to:

```
mock_df_x.loc.__setitem__.assert_called_with((False, 'atr'), 0)
```

which works if you are trying to assign a value to that key.
Notice the extra parameter, too, corresponding to the value you are actually trying to assign.